# postfix-Postfwd rate limit

Tags: email, postfix, postfwd

I have total 4000 mail for an outgoing recipient and I want to send mail 2 mail every 1 minute. so I have configured postfwd.

```
#/etc/postfwd.cf
id=RATE01 ; action=rate($$recipient_domain/1/60/450 4.7.1 Message delivery request rate limit exceeded)
```

and

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
                      permit_mynetworks,
                check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:10040,
                permit_sasl_authenticated,
                127.0.0.1:10040_time_limit = 3600,
                reject_unauth_destination
```

after 2 mails all the mails rejected and mailq empty. my requirment is send 2 mail and hold the mail for 1 minutes and send mail again.

Comment: The `check_policy_service` PostFWD doesn't hold mails: it rejects them with a (temporary 450) error after the limit has exceed. I think you have missunderstood the purpose of the tutorial you were following.

Comment: is it possible for rate limit through postfwd. send 2 mail in 1 minute and again send

Comment: Is it possible to limit this in your software generating these mails?

Comment: no. actually, I'm using centos 7. my injector, inject the mail in postfix and server send the mail outside.

Comment: cloud you tell me how to rate limit for outgoing. my requirement 2 mail every 1 minute.

Answer (score 0):

Your current PostFWD rate limiting approach affects mail before it gets to queue, causing your Postfix to reject mail.

Take a look at these configuration parameters that controls behaviour of outbound connections:

> **`default_destination_rate_delay` (default: `0s`)**
>
> The default amount of delay that is inserted between individual
>   deliveries to the same destination; the resulting behavior depends on
>   the value of the corresponding per-destination recipient limit.
>
> **`default_destination_recipient_limit` (default: `50`)**
>
> The default maximal number of recipients per message delivery. This is
>   the default limit for delivery via the lmtp(8), pipe(8), smtp(8) and
>   virtual(8) delivery agents.

Comment: i m using a default parameter but all the mail sent in immediately. initial_destination_concurrency = 1
default_destination_rate_delay = 60s
default_destination_concurrency_limit = 10
default_destination_recipient_limit = 2
master.cf:-  smtp     unix    -         -        n      -       10       smtp

Comment: Thank you. parameres working well. but I have 7 IP address for sending mail I need to rotate IP address for outgoing mail